# MS Outlook 2013 and Trello - Forward message as an attachment action

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013, trello

I have set up a Quick Step within Outlook 2013 to forward the current message that I have open as an attachment to Trello.  After clicking the quick step the message is attached to the email however the .msg extension is removed.  If I save my message manually it saves the message with the .msg extension although then I have to manually create a new email and attach the file or go to Trello and create a card and attach the email with the .msg extension (defeating the purpose and ease of a quick step). I've found that an email attachment passed into Trello without an extension will not open when I download it again at a later date.  If I manually attach the email with the .msg extension then I can download, view (within Outlook) and act on the email as I normally would.  Does anyone know a way to force Outlook to use the .msg extension on a "forward message as an attachment" action within Quick Steps?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason that it has to have an .msg extension?

Here's what I did to get my emails from Outlook into Trello so that I can keep myself straight.

In Outlook under the "Respond" header I chose the "more" which gave the option to forward as attachment.

I chose the drop down of "more" and then right clicked the "forward as attachment" and added it to the quick access bar at the VERY top of the page.  That lets me do all of those steps with one click of the button now.

I added the email address for the Trello board and now I just use the board address to forward to -- this allows the email to be in Trello so if I do have to follow up, I can just click the EML attachement and the email appears.

Hope this helps,

Mindy